# rich:select with enableManualInput="true" doesn't fire listener

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I'm trying to set up an "editable combo-box" using rich:select with enableManualInput="true".

I'm having problems handling "wrong" user input: if the user types a value which is NOT included in the list of selectable "selectItems", I would like to restore the previous value of the field. But, I cannot find a way to attach an effective event hander (be it javascript or server-side) to be triggered in this situation.

```
<rich:select id="tracoChoice"

    value="#{customerActivitiesController.selectedTraco}"

    enableManualInput="true">

    <f:selectItems value="#{customerActivitiesController.selectableTracos}"/>

    <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{customerActivitiesController.onSelectedTracoChange}" render="currentCustomerActivity"/>

</rich:select>
```

If I select a value from the drop-down, onSelectedTracoChange() is called as expected. If I just type a random value in the input field (and then press ENTER, or TAB), onSelectedTracoChange is not called.

I also experimented with valueChangeListener, to no avail.  On the javascript side, I tried various combinations involving onblur and onchange, but these fire for normal value selection as well. I just thought there must be a simpler way that escapes me...

Answer (score 0):

There's no event fired since you're technically not selecting anything.

You can simply use onkeyup or other events, but you can't do that just with `<a4j:ajax>` since you need to filter them:

```
<a4j:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="if (event.keyCode == 13) { resetInput(); }" />

<a4j:jsFunction name="resetInput" actionListener="#{customerActivitiesController.onSelectedTracoChange}" />
```

keycode 13 is Enter, Tab is 9

EDIT
if you need to send a value to the server you can do it like this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="resetInput" actionListener="#{customerActivitiesController.onSelectedTracoChange}" >
    <a4j:param name="input" assignTo="#{bean.value}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

this will allow you to pass a parameter to that function

```
resetInput(RichFaces.$(clientIdOfSelect).getInput().val())
```

Comment: Tried that, the problem is that value (i.e. customerActivitiesController.selectedTraco) doesn't get updated until some value is selected. If I type something outside the list then trigger any event it takes the old value.

Comment: In that case get the value by JavaScript and send it to the server by the jsFunction.

Comment: You mean by getting the value from the control by name? If so could you please provide code example.